# Get the list of all spreadsheets associated with Google account using Sheets API v4

Tags: java, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

Using Google Sheets API v4, I am looking to get the list of spreadsheets attached to my account. I did much research but have not found any solutions for that.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To get list of all files of specific type, you can use drive API v3.
Below is an example to get all sheets from drive of authenticated user.

```
drive.files.list({
    q: "mimeType='application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet'",
    fields: 'nextPageToken, files(id, name)'
}, (err, response) => {
    //Your code
})
```

You can pass file type in MIME type as 'q' parameter. You can get list of drive MIME types [here](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/mime-types).

source: https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/migration#list_spreadsheets_for_the_authenticated_user

Answer (score 12):

The v4 API doesn't offer a way to list spreadsheets. You'll need to use the Drive API.  The [Migrate from a previous API page](https://developers.google.com/sheets/guides/migration#list_spreadsheets_for_the_authenticated_user) has some details on how to do use the Drive API to do it.

Comment: I've been searching this for 6 hours, But Hey @Sam But how read this response, Looks like XML is not formatted well. Can I get JSON response

Answer (score 0):

For that, you have to use Drives API.

```
from apiclient import discovery

credentials = get_credential_service_account()
service = discovery.build('drive', 'v3', credentials=credentials)
service.drive().list()
```

For obtaining "credentials", you can use [this code](https://gist.github.com/kmonsoor/d89c930a8df3060106c04648dc6058b0).

Google's official doc is here: https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/changes/list

Answer (score 0):

Java Implementation :

String `url="https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/filesq=mimeType='application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet'";`

```
public String getSheets(String url) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {

   RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
      HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
      headers.add("Authorization", "Bearer " + "Access Token"); 
      HttpEntity entity = new HttpEntity(headers);
      HttpEntity<String> response = restTemplate.exchange(url, HttpMethod.GET, entity, String.class);
      return response.getBody();
}
```

Access token can be generated by using below link
[OAUth Plyaground](https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground/)