# How to fetch script ids of spreadsheet bound project?

Tags: google-apps-script

I have 500+ spreadsheets in my G-Suit drive and each spreadsheet has a bound script. Is there a way to fetch the script ids using App Script APIs?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get the list of all spreadsheets associated with Google account using Sheets API v4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37876423/get-the-list-of-all-spreadsheets-associated-with-google-account-using-sheets-api)

Comment: Unfortunately, in the current stage, there are no APIs and methods for retrieving the project ID of the container-bound script yet. On the other hand, when the project ID of the container-bound script is found, the file ID of parent Google Docs can be retrieved. Also the project ID of the standalone project can be retrieved. For your situation, there is a Feature Request. https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/111149037